# Problemas com espaços entre li's

Tags: css, css3

Bom Dia!

Vejam a figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o seguinte css

```
ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros {
    clear:both;
}

ul.listaTopo {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}

ul.listaTopo li, ul.listaRegistros li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

E o seguinte html

```
<h1 class="h1Centralizado">Listagem de Clientes</h1><br />

<div class="divLista" style="width:800px">
  <ul class="listaTopo">
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:300px">NOME</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:200px">BAIRRO</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:100px">BLOQUEIO</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:100px">EDITAR</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:100px">EXCLUIR</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="listaRegistros">
    <li style='text-align:left; width:300px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'>José Mário
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:left; width:200px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'>São</li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='?acao=bloqdes&bloq=s&idCliente=1' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este Cliente?')" '><img src='_img/bloquear.png' height=30px  title='Bloquear Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='clientesEditar.php?acao=form&idCliente=1'><img src='_img/editar.png' height='30px' title='Editar Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='?acao=excluir&idCliente=1' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este Cliente?')" '><img src='_img/excluir.png' height='30px'  title='Excluir Cliente'/></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ul class='listaRegistros'>
    <li style='text-align:left; width:300px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'>Carlos Aberto Ferreira Rocha
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:left; width:200px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'>São</li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='?acao=bloqdes&bloq=s&idCliente=2' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este Cliente?')" '><img src='_img/bloquear.png' height=30px  title='Bloquear Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='clientesEditar.php?acao=form&idCliente=2'><img src='_img/editar.png' height='30px' title='Editar Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='?acao=excluir&idCliente=2' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este Cliente?')" '><img src='_img/excluir.png' height='30px'  title='Excluir Cliente'/></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div style="clear:both; height:50px; width:100%;"> </div>
```

Se observarem, a `ul` `listaTopo`, a cada `li`, tem um espaço entre elas. Mas a `ul` `listaRegistros`, com o mesmo `style`, não esta dando esse espaço entre as suas `li's`.

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Não relacionado ao seu problema, mas me parece redundante usar "listaLi", não? já poderia usar o próprio `li` como seletor. Por exemplo `<ul class="listaRegistros meuLi">` e no CSS `.meuli li {....` assim evita ficar repetindo a classe nos LIs (isso se for usar em vários ULs diferentes, senão bastaria no CSS `.listaRegistros li, .listaTopo li {...}`

Comment: sim. agente vai aprendendo.. Já alterei aqui. Mas então, alguma ideia desse meu erro?

Comment: Aparentemente os espaços vem da quebra de linha entre os LIs. Experimente (como teste apenas) tirar os fechamentos dos </li> e comente se algo mudou. Deixe só os <li> mas tire os </li> e diga se os espaços sumiram. Se resolver, uma possível solução é colocar os fechamentos de volta, mas encostados com o <li> seguinte

Comment: cada li é uma coluna. Ma porque não deu o erro na ul de baixo?

Comment: Provavelmente por causa dos outros elementos dentro. Veja uns exemplos aqui de como remover espaços de inline-block. Está em inglês, mas os códigos são faceis de entender: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ - Basicamente são mudanças na formatação do HTML, e não no conteúdo. O problema é que tab e quebras de linha normalmente contam como espaço.

Comment: Agora, uma observação: essa sua lista de registros provavelmente deveria ser uma table, e não uma UL. dados tabulares são formatados com `table`. UL é pra listas simples.

Comment: Olha só: É estranho pois o style de um é o mesmo do outro, dentro da primeira ul só tem texto (padrão: inline). Na ul de baixo, as li's estão sendo populadas com dados vindo do banco que nada mais são que textos também. Confere? Apenas as 3 ultimas opções são links. Não consigo entender porque isso ocorre!

Comment: Na verdade ocorrer é normal, o estranho é não aparecer nas outras (pode ser mera questão deles existirem, mas estarem alinhados com alguma outra coisa) :)  - de qualquer forma, experimente alguma das alterações que eu comentei na página linkada, pra ver se é isso mesmo ou se tem algum outro problema.

Comment: tirando o /li resolveu. Mas serrá porque não deu nas de baixo? Não encontro lógica. hehehe. cheguei até fazer margin: 0 e paddindg: 0 e nada

Comment: Uma das soluções é devolver os </li>, mas em vez de por no fim da linha, ponha junto da seguinte. Por exemplo, no segundo li vc fecha o primeiro: `</li><li>Segundo li` pula linha `</li><li>Terceiro li` e assim vai. Tem outros exemplos naquele link, veja qual fica melhor para formatar o seu código. Na verdade estamos mudando o espaço de lugar apenas. Outra saída seria trocar o `inline-block` por `float:left`. - mas seu caso é tipíco para `table`, na verdade, e não de `ul`. O UL além de semanticamente inadequado nesse contexto vai te dar outras dores de cabeça além dessa.

Comment: Sim. A ideia de usar ul, e aí te peço um conselho, uma opnião, é que esse sistema vai rodar em mobies também e desejo colocar cada li em uma linha e cada ul com uma cor diferente e então com tabelas não dá certo pois vão ficar em linhas e colunas. Alguma orientação à esse respeito?

Comment: Se quiser colocar essa solução como resposta, eu aceito ela como respondia!

Comment: Sem ver o layout todo realmente é complicado eu palpitar, talvez seja mais facil fazer tudo com div então, ou usar alguma daquelas soluções pra "matar" os espaços. Talvez o mais simples seja por tudo numa linha só: `<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li>...`

Comment: mesmo assim. muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que *inline-block* não funcina quando você precisa utilizar a largura total com vários elementos, por causa dos já citados *white-spaces* ou espaço em branco.

Uma das soluções possíveis é utilizar `float` nos elementos:

#### Exemplo:

```css
ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.listaTopo {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;

}
ul.listaTopo::after, ul.listaRegistros::after {
  display:block;
  content:'';
  clear:both;
}

ul.listaTopo li, ul.listaRegistros li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h1Centralizado">Listagem de Clientes</h1><br />

<div class="divLista" style="width:800px">
  <ul class="listaTopo">
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:300px">NOME</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:200px">BAIRRO</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:100px">BLOQUEIO</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:100px">EDITAR</li>
    <li class="listaLi" style="width:100px">EXCLUIR</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="listaRegistros">
    <li style='text-align:left; width:300px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'>José Mário
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:left; width:200px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'>São</li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='?acao=bloqdes&bloq=s&idCliente=1' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este Cliente?')"><img src='_img/bloquear.png' height=30px  title='Bloquear Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='clientesEditar.php?acao=form&idCliente=1'><img src='_img/editar.png' height='30px' title='Editar Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#CCC; color:#FFF'><a href='?acao=excluir&idCliente=1' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este Cliente?')"><img src='_img/excluir.png' height='30px'  title='Excluir Cliente'/></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ul class='listaRegistros'>
    <li style='text-align:left; width:300px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'>Carlos Aberto Ferreira Rocha
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:left; width:200px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'>São</li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='?acao=bloqdes&bloq=s&idCliente=2' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este Cliente?')"><img src='_img/bloquear.png' height=30px  title='Bloquear Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='clientesEditar.php?acao=form&idCliente=2'><img src='_img/editar.png' height='30px' title='Editar Cliente' /></a>
    </li>
    <li style='text-align:center; width:100px; background-color:#FFF; color:#CCC'><a href='?acao=excluir&idCliente=2' onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este Cliente?')"><img src='_img/excluir.png' height='30px'  title='Excluir Cliente'/></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div style="clear:both; height:50px; width:100%;"> </div>
```

Nesse caso eu apenas removi as *margins* e *paddings* dos elementos *li* e *ul*

```
ul.listaTopo, ul.listaRegistros {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.listaTopo li, ul.listaRegistros li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Adicionei um *clear-fix* após cada `ul`:

```
ul.listaTopo::after, ul.listaRegistros::after {
  display:block;
  content:'';
  clear:both;
}
```

E flutuei os `li`:

```
ul.listaTopo li, ul.listaRegistros li {
    float:left;
}
```

Outra opção é [remover os espaços em brancos entre as tags](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), como [já citado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126221/problemas-com-espa%C3%A7os-entre-lis?newsletter=1&nlcode=489466%7Cdb26#comment263157_126221).

**Obs.:** Parece-me que você deseja fazer uma tabluação de dados, nesse caso o adequado é utilizar `table` e não `ul`.

Comment: Entendi. Mas, e na hora de mostrar a table em um celular 320x480? Como fazer com a table?

Comment: @CarlosRocha você pode criar uma página para _desktop's_ e outra apenas para _celulares_. Existem [ferramentas muito eficientes pra detectar o dispositivo](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) do usuário.

Comment: Mas caso não queira fazer isso, você pode apenas corrigir o teu CSS/HTML com o código da resposta. Não é que a forma que você está tentando está errada, nada disso. Apenas é mais convencional utilizar tabela para tabulação de dados, mas em alguns casos pode ser que tabelas não funcionem, como no caso da responsividade da tabulação, nesse caso o uso de `li` parece-me mais adequado.

Comment: entendi, obrigado pelo retorno. Vou ver isso com calma.